# Check if number is perfect prime recursively c++

Tags: c++, recursion, boolean

I've been assigned to write a program that checks if a number is perfect prime or not (the sum of its digits is prime, the sum of the sum of its digits is prime...). I've stumbled upon two extreme cases that break my program:

```
INPUT: 20328307  OUTPUT: true (expected false)
INPUT: 587899597 OUTPUT: true (expected false)
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


bool is_prime(int n) {
    if (n == 0 or n == 1) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i == n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int sum_of_digits(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

bool is_perfect_prime(int n) {
    if (sum_of_digits(n) >= 10) is_perfect_prime(sum_of_digits(n)); //cas recursiu
    return is_prime(n); //cas base

}

int main() {
    int n;
    while (cin >> n) cout << (is_perfect_prime(n) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

I can't see where this script fails for these two values, and why it doesn't fail for smaller numbers.

Comment: `is_perfect_prime` just calls itself recursively, ignoring the return value. So I'm surprised your program works at all.

Comment: loop should be `for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {` instead. And 1 is considered a prime, no?

Comment: Unrelated: Look into using a prime sieving algorithm and memoization to speed up `is_prime`

Comment: @slava no. Prime excludes 1.

Comment: The text "extreme cases" is a bit deceiving. It fails on many ordinary values, like 35 or 91.

Comment: Also, `13` is not a perfect prime, but your logic in `is_perfect_prime` would let it through because `1+3 < 10`. Are you really claiming that your code works correctly on all numbers less than 20328307?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux loop will end with false value when i becomes big enough

Comment: When you have known failure cases, you have a perfect opportunity to break out the debugging software that came with your development environment and step through the code to see where the program does something you don't expect. The unexpected is quite often a bug, and when it isn't, it's a misunderstanding of how the algorithm is supposed to work. Either needs fixing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code is rubbish from start to finish.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I do not follow why there would be UB here?

Comment: I'm not joining in on that close reason because sometimes the right answer to a question is  "You can't beat this code into behaving the way you want it to in any reasonable amount of time. Junk it and start over." It's an unsatisfying answer, but it is an answer.

Comment: @Slava I misunderstood the loop.

Comment: Consider testing `is_prime` and `sum_of_digits` separately. Make sure they are both working correctly with a wide variety of inputs before trying to use them together.

Comment: It also fails for 15, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your for loop is incorrect, it should be instead:

```
 for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
     if (n % i == 0) return false;
 }
```

otherwise you return true almost on every non even number. Second you ignore result of recursive call, possible solution is:

```
bool is_perfect_prime(int n) {
    if ( n >= 10 and not is_perfect_prime(sum_of_digits(n)) )
        return false;
    return is_prime(n); //cas base
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution is incorrect. For an input of 13, this will return true. The if statement should be changed to `if (n>= 10) return is_perfect_prime(sum);`

Comment: @joelw I see that it should be n instead of sum. But your condition is not correct either. Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've got it to work. The problem was in the is_prime() for loop and in the recursive case of is_perfect_prime(). This is what I've come up  with:

```
bool is_prime(int n) {
    if (n == 0 or n == 1) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int sum_of_digits(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

bool is_perfect_prime(int n) {
    if (n < 10) return is_prime(n);
    if (! is_prime(n)) return false;
    return is_perfect_prime(sum_of_digits(n));
}
```

Thanks for your answers.